# The position of "in addition to"

Tags: word-order

I wrote

> Contextual rules are in the form of condition-action where in the condition part, **in addition to the features of the matching node**, the properties of the matching context are specified.

Is it correct? or it is maybe:

> Contextual rules are in the form of condition-action where in the condition part, the properties of the matching context **in addition to the features of the matching node** are specified.

or even:

> Contextual rules are in the form of condition-action where in the condition part, the properties of the matching context are specified **in addition to the features of the matching node**.

Answer (score 1):

It can be more clear if you write it as this:

> Contextual rules are in the form of condition-action, where in the condition part, **both** the properties of the matching context **and** the features of the matching node are specified.

I feel no ambiguity reading it like this.

Answer (score 1):

All of your sentences are grammatical and mean the same thing. You transposed them well.

I think the third option is the clearest.

The only thing I would suggest is adding commas or em dashes:

In your second option:

> Contextual rules are in the form of condition-action where **{, or —}** in the condition part **{, or —}** the properties of the matching context **[,]** in addition to the features of the matching node **[,]** are specified.

In your third option:

> Contextual rules are in the form of condition-action where **{, or —}** in the condition part **{, or —}** the properties of the matching context are specified in addition to the features of the matching node.